# Importing Objects at Runtime into Unity3d/iOS VR program

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, stl, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have a conceptual question, and might be barking up the wrong tree. I've been intrigued with the Cardboard/Unity3d/iOS pipeline for writing VR apps. I am trying to make a very basic STL viewer. What I would like to do is to import STL files, possibly though iCloud, into the app for viewing.

I'm learning about asset bundles in Unity as a way to import objects into a program. The problem with this is that they have to be prepared prior to runtime and have specific references.

Is there a way to import STL files into Unity at runtime without creating asset bundles beforehand? If not, does anyone know of a combination of available software/pipeline to complete this task? I particularly like the cardboard framework, but it seems to support iOS you have to use Unity.

Any/all guidance appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch your STL file into Unity, there's the WWW class : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

```
// on iOS, persistent data path is the "Documents" application folder that you can access through iTunes to put STL files in if you build your application wit hthe "Application uses iTunes file sharing" option in XCode
WWW www1 = new WWW(string.Format("file:///{0}/{1}", Application.persistentDataPath, FileName));

// simple URL on the Internet works too
WWW www2 = new WWW(string.Format("http://{0}/{1}", FilePath, FileName));
```

You have to code your STL parser. There's many out there but STL is a really simple format and you should not have any difficulty writing your own. Then you create your mesh : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

Once you have your mesh, add a MeshRenderer component to any game object then asign the mesh to it : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshRenderer.html